# WebStorm navigate bar setting?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I need to change my WebStorm nav bar style from first into second:

[image]

[image]

The first does not contain file tab, as well as I can not split vertically file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to change my WebStorm nav bar style

It's not a "nav bar" -- it's Editor Tabs bar.

The actual Navigation Bar is present on both screenshots and it is just above it (the bar that shows `new.OrderList.js` in it on first screenshot).

---

In any case: the Editor Tabs bar can be re-enabled again at:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Editor Tabs`
3. Set `Placement` to be anything else than "None" -- to be as on 2nd screenshot it should be set to "Top"

[image]